# What is the best algorithm for replacing characters without using nested for loops?

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose that I will be having a string consists of 3 letters 'a', 'b', 'c' and I need to shorten the string by replacing every two characters with the 3rd character. What is the best way to do it?

example:

- aa (no change, substitution only done with different characters)
- bcab > a ab > a c > b (NOT bbb, because b is the shortest)
- aba > ca > b
- a (no change)

I did the following, but I guess there is a better solution or algorithm:

```
def replaceChar(input_string):  
     possibilites = {'ab':'c',
                     'bc':'a', 
                     'ca':'b',
                     'cb':'a', 
                     'ac':'b', 
                     'ba':'c'
                     }
     for key, value in possibilites.items():
          input_string = input_string.replace(key, value)
          char_game(input_string)

def char_game(input_string):
        if len( list(set(input_string)) ) == 1: print(input_string)
        elif len( list(set(input_string)) ) >= 2 : replaceChar(input_string)
        else: print( input_string )
```

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  `aba: ca > b` What is the meaning of the colon vs. the greater-than sign?

Comment: @JohnGordon I mean that for the string 'aba': the first iteration should substitute 'ab' with 'c' so now it's 'ca'. The section iteration should substitute 'ca' with 'b'. and no further substitution need if the remaining is one character of similar characters.

Comment: The innocent comment "(NOT bbb) because b is the shortest" makes this a very hard problem indeed if you require a minimum length result. Your code doesn't guarantee this.

Comment: @Gene yeah i don't really understand how could it return `bbb`. to OP: what will be output if input is `bbbb` ?

Comment: @Tiendung He's talking about starting with bcab and replacing ca with b.

Comment: @Gene oh, thanks, I understand now.

Comment: @Hathout please give some more examples with a long string. There are lots of unclear things here. What if the input is `bbbb` or `bbaabb` ?

Also, your code doesn't run. The 2 function are calling each other, which throws `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: (I'd be surprised shown a polynomial time solution.)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @gene that your solution might not give the best possible solution.
But, if you want to go with your approach, then following O(N) solution with an additional stack might do the trick

```
def getchar(input_string):
    rep = {
        'ab':'c',
        'bc':'a',
        'ca':'b',
        'cb':'a',
        'ac':'b',
        'ba':'c'
    }
    stack = []
    for c in input_string:
        t = c
        while len(stack) and stack[-1] != t:
            t = rep[t+stack[-1]]
            stack.pop()
        stack.append(t)
    return stack
```

Comment: consider changing variable name `str` to something, since `str` is a built-in function.

Comment: This got *nested loops*: see title. I don't see that it always gives the shortest string - it succeeds with *bacb*, fails with *acbb*.

Comment: @greybeard so what if the input is `bbbb` ? I don't get it. Should it outputs `bbbb` or just `b` ?

Comment: @Tiendung The answer, in this case, is bbbb. We only substitute two different letters with the 3rd. if it become bbbb for some reason, It will go with the code inside the 1st IF statement if len( list(set(input_string)) ) == 1: print(input_string). The condition return the different currecters in the string and if it's len = 1, print it as a final solution. So bbbb will become 'b' and len('b') = 1 so the result will be bbbb.

Comment: @Hathout please answer my comment on your post, this is just ksholla's answer.